# textbox long integer value showing as exponential type in angualrjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have textbox and value is assigned by model

```
<input class="form-control" type='text' ng-focus='getFocusEl($event)' ng-change='profileNameValidate(profileData.profileName)' ng-model='profileData.profileName' maxlength="64">
```

If that textbox value coming from api as

```
1223424534568878687676786786786876786786786786876767867868768768
```

While showing in text box `1.2234245345688787e+63`

I need to show full length integer in textbox.

How to do that?

Comment: Why Do You Want To Do That ? And From Usability Perspective It Will Be Difficult Right?

Comment: And Is The Value From Server If Its In integer  Format Then You Can Convert It To String.

Comment: server sending as string only

Comment: try using String(passyournumber)

Comment: I have tried with String() also. This behavior comes oly for textbox. remaining places it is showing full length value

Comment: Can You Post Me The JSON Output You Get It From Server?

Comment: Example Is It Going To Be Like This?
http://echo.jsontest.com/val/1223424534568878687676786786786876786786786786876767867868768768/val/1223424534568878687676786786786876786786786786876767867868768768

Comment: Check This Link And Reply  Back If You Have Any Doubts http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/4208/

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to stringify the value before setting it to the textbox.Further you can leverage the getter setter function if you are using angular >=1.3.

```
<input class="form-control" type='text' ng-focus='getFocusEl($event)' ng-change='profileNameValidate(profileData.profileName)' ng-model='profileData.profileName.getString' maxlength="64"
ng-model-options=" {getterSetter: true }">
```

And then in your controller

```
$scope.profileData.profileName.getString: function (value) {
  if (angular.isDefined(value)) {
    $scope.profileData.profileName = value;
  } else {        
    return $scope.profileData.profileName.toString();
  );
 }
}
```

For more info see section Binding getter/setter [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: Why we need to do that?. What is the behavoiur

Comment: This way , whenever a ng-model changes , it will call the getter method for that ng-model , and you will have full control over the value to be returned.You can truncate/stringify/update etc it in that function.Also if toString does not work try appending a blank space at the end.